# Por que uma requisição POST é redirecionada para localhost usando AngularJS e apache2?

Tags: angularjs

Estou fazendo uma requisição POST para usar uma API de autentificação. O código exemplo, funciona perfeitamente no servidor original [nesta documentação](https://www.tutlane.com/example/angularjs/angularjs-http-post-method-example)

Segue o código usado:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>
         AngularJs $http.post() Service Method Example
      </title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         var app = angular.module('postserviceApp', []);
app.controller('postserviceCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.name = null;
    $scope.age = null;
    $scope.adress = null;
    $scope.lblMsg = null;
    $scope.postdata = function(name, age, adress) {
        var data = {
            "email": "meuemail@emaul.com",
            "password": "minhasenha"
        };
        //Call the services

        const serverApp = '​https://apiadmin.tindin.com.br/login';
        $http.post(serverApp, JSON.stringify(data)).then(function(response) {
            if (response.data)
                $scope.msg = "Post Data Submitted Successfully!";
        }, function(response) {
            $scope.msg = "Service not Exists";
            $scope.statusval = response.status;
            $scope.statustext = response.statusText;
            $scope.headers = response.headers();
        });
    };
});
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>AngularJS Http Post Method Example</h2>
      <div ng-app="postserviceApp" ng-controller="postserviceCtrl">
         <div>
            Name : <input ng-model="name" /><br/><br/>
            Age : <input ng-model="age" /><br/><br/>
            Adress : <input ng-model="adress" /><br/><br/>
            <input type="button" value="Send" ng-click="postdata(name, age, adress)" /> <br/><br/>
         </div>
         <p>Output Message : {{msg}}</p>
         <p>StatusCode: {{statusval}}</p>
         <p>Status: {{statustext}}</p>
         <p>Response Headers: {{headers}}</p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

No entanto, quando executo o mesmo código usando o localhost com apache2, o envio do POST é redirecionado para localhost + endereço da API. Acusando que o serviço não existe. Seque a mensagem do console:

> POST
> http://localhost/%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%E2%80%B9https://apiadmin.tindin.com.br/login
> 404 (Not Found)

Segue mensagem da aplicação:

> Output Message : Service not Exists

Gostaria de saber o motivo por qual isso acontece, e como posso corrigir.

Comment: `http://localhost/%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%E2%80%B9https://apiadmin.tindin.com.br/login` esse trecho aparentemente tem uma concatenação inesperada. Deve ter percebido que o exemplo da API usa caminho relativo, e o seu está usando absoluto. Não lembro muito bem mais como usar o angularjs, mas deve haver alguma configuração para isso. (o seu especificamente é a versão 1.4, que é mais "velhinho")

Comment: Pode testar com [esse exemplo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers)? Talvez você precise apenas substituir `$http.post` por `$http({})`

Comment: Sua pista estava correta! Consegui mudar o destino do arquivo ao declarar o caminho da variável fora da função, no início do módulo.
Ao invés de eu fazer    const url = 'minhaAPI' ; http.post(url.....eu fiz  const url 'minhaAPI'; module[].......function(.....)

Gostaria de fazer as honras e postar como resposta? Só para ninguém mais passar por esse problema

Comment: depois vou ter que formatar isso como em forma de resposta. Mas se poder fazer isso, seria legal